# Issue with Json Array using RoboSpice

Tags: json, robospice, spring-android

I am trying to parse the following JSON array:

```
[{"desc": "A coffee-based beverage or dessert. Usually refers to the act of topping a drink or dessert with esp...", "image_url": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/Affogato.JPG/800px-Affogato.JPG", "id": "affogato", "name": "Affogato"}, {"desc": "A style of coffee prepared by adding hot water to espresso, giving a similar strength to but differe...", "image_url": "", "id": "americano", "name": "Caffe Americano"}]
```

my java code:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CoffeeList extends ArrayList<Coffee> {

    public CoffeeList() {
    }
}

@Override
public CoffeeList loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(baseUrl, CoffeeList.class);
}
```

RESULT:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

"Exception occurred during invocation of web service."

What DO i do  ?

Comment: Make sure your api getRestTemplate().getForObject(baseUrl, CoffeeList.class); is returning the CoffeeList.

Also, Your tagging of your class CoffeeList.class is the same with your api response.

Comment: Could you please post the whole stacktrace?